# How to remove noitification observer in another class?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have created a notification in class-A like

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(methodcalled:) name:@"ViewChanged" object:nil];
```

I am posting this notification with name in class-B like

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"ViewChanged" object:nil];
```

Now I want to remove this notification like below in class-C. Is it possible? As I need to go to class-A from class-c.

```
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"ViewChanged" object:nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:nil name:@"ViewChanged" object:nil];
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

I tried but the notification is not removing and its calling two times.
How to create object for `NSNotificationCenter`?

Comment: Why should C be managing the observation of A? Why isn't A doing it for itself?

Comment: You would need a reference to the instance of that object (of Class-A) to use the removeObserver:instanceOfObjectOfClass-A.

Comment: @Wain, Before going to A from C i want to remove observer of A. otherwise it will another one. Now when i go from C to A the method is calling two times.

Comment: How to create an instance for NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: A should know if it is an observer and remove itself when appropriate / not re-add itself.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:nil name:@"ViewChanged" object:nil];
```

Your code is not working since the first parameter to removeObserver is nil, as explained in the documentation.

> - (void)removeObserver:(id)notificationObserver name:(NSString *)notificationName object:(id)notificationSender
>
> notificationObserver
>
> Observer to remove from the dispatch table. Specify an observer to remove only entries for this observer. Must not
>   be nil, or message will have no effect.

**A possible solution:**

`objectA` could listen for a second notification, such as `removeA`. You then create a method within `objectA` which removes `objectA` as the observer for `ViewChanged`. `removeA` should trigger that method.

`objectC` would then only have to post the `removeA` notification and `objectA` would stop listening.

Comment: Having a notification for the sole purpose of removing another is a rather contrapted solution.

Comment: This was my best attempt. @G.Ganesh hinted that he has already introduced the _Mediator Pattern_ into his design, indicating a requirement for _message coupling (low coupling)_. Unless _communicational cohesion_ is a problem, I believe that the solution I proposed is valid in the context.

Answer (score -1):

As @Wain correctly says, it's weird/wrong design.  Buy if you really want to, you need to do:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:objectA name:@"ViewChanged" object:nil];
```

So `objectA` is the object you passed as `self` when you called `addObserver:`.  That you now need to get `objectA` to the instance of class C is an indication that what you're trying to do is wrong/weird.

Comment: No, that would increase coupling since C has to know about A.

Comment: @Pétur Yes I know, that's why I said it's weird.  I think that adding a notification for the sole purpose of removing another, as you suggested, creates an even bigger mess.

Comment: @Pétur, How the C come to know about A?

Comment: @G.Ganesh If C doesn't know about A, then why do you want to remove A before C starts listening to notification? Once they are independent, you don't care.